# gcc free() crashing in multithreaded environment only

Tags: multithreading, gcc, free

## problem:

My app is randomly crashing on a call to free().

## Question

Does anyone have any hints on what could be causing `free()` to fail like so? should I add some memory boundary ops?  any GCC options or threading details I may have missed?

### context:

I am a seasoned C coder and I have never had such a screwed up problem.  it's basically killing 4 months of work.  In an environment with unit testing, and constant code cleanup.

this is a TCP server using winsock 2 `select()`.

compiling with gcc on windows 10:
`gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0`

The same code, only crashes when running within a sub thread.  attempts to re-create the problem have all failed in single thread test loops and ***severe*** torture tests.

Interesting fact is that ***the app doesn't crash when running within GDB***.

I even have an allocation/de-allocation management layer (used by my code and libs) which dumps every single call to `calloc()` and `free()` within a table.  A further dump analysis tool verifies all memory management and the result is that all `free()` are properly balanced (I have no double de-allocation or stray pointer being freed).

with my analysis tool, the actual pointer has been a mix of a fresh memory address and a recycled pointer.  so it doesn't seem to be related to be from re-using mem from the free list (I have dozens of reused addresses prior to the crash, after memory analysis).

when running under a thread, that code doesn't share any memory with the main thread, it basically launches a worker which does ALL of the work.  there is currently only one sub thread, so it cannot be a worker-thread collision.  main thread does nothing a part for waiting on tcp port and adding a node to a thread pool manager.

Posting code is not useful, as the bug is not reproducible outside of it running in a sub-thread within my main app... i.e. it does not seem to be a logic issue.

running the same code from the main thread will not cause any crash!

The failing `free()` is always happening in a specific combination of data being processed, but it can be successful an indeterminate amount of times before failing, and the same function is called MANY other times on equivalent data and doesn't fail.

Comment: Seems like you have covered the normal situations. The other situations is that you have written into memory and corrupted data. So the next thing would be to look for buffer overruns (in both main a sub threads). Try using [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/)

Comment: How difficult/reliable is crash replication? Could you use techniques like removing some calls to `free` and seeing if the crash goes away or adding "safety buffers" to allocations and seeing if the crash goes away?

Comment: @MartinYork last I checked, using valgrind on windows seemed pretty complex.  can I use valgrind thru WSL to test my windows app?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  adding buffers would be easy to do (through my mem mgt layer)... it would at least be interesting to see if it changes the symptoms.

Comment: Do you have the ability to run a tool like `valgrind` or the like to see if there’s some sort of memory error here? That might be the root cause.

Comment: Another thing worth trying is increasing the warning level on the compiler and treat all warnings as errors and fix them. That may help you find potential undefined behavior.

Comment: `Interesting fact is that the app doesn't crash when running within GDB.` Pretty common for undefined behavior. The debug/release builds are very different and can use different version of the standard libraries.

Comment: @templatetypedef running on windows and this app is not setup for linux, so AFAIK, valgrind is out of the question.

Comment: @MartinYork wrt `-Wall`,  good advice for sure, that's how I compile all of my code. the only warnings I leave are unused vars and set but unused vars, which inevitably occur when switching some debugging defines.

Comment: am implementing a page protected allocator (something I've done in another project) which basically adds write protected VM pages around allocations and forces return addresses to be on page edges, so that any memory overflow (or underflow, if switched) generates an exception immediately... I hope this works and I do find some code clobbering stray memory.

Comment: AddressSanitizer ought to be available on Windows, I think.  Try building with `-fsanitize=address`?  There's also a ThreadSanitizer to help find races.

Comment: Have you tried it with heap checker tools, like [Dr. Memory](https://drmemory.org/) or [heob](https://github.com/ssbssa/heob)?

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks for note ThreadSanitizer , will check it out if I ever have such a problem (race).

Comment: @ssbssa finally didn't have to go there.

Comment: @moliad I'm pretty sure these tools would have shown you the problem, and you wouldn't have had to create the special allocation technique.

Answer (score 0):

finally found the problem.

A strange issue occurred within my code where a Negative memory allocation size was generated and my `malloc()` using code didn't trap the problem and returned a bogus address.

the actual `malloc()` having failed, trying to free it, was an error.

I was able to trap it by doing direct VM allocation and protecting pages between each allocation.

When my code tried to `memmove()` within the flawed address, it generated an OS access exception and I was able to track the bug right when it happened.

Finally, as far as I can tell, it had nothing to do with the threading code.  I still feel it's strange it didn't crash within the gdb.

thanks for all who gave me ideas to look into.